# Flutter: Video player not initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, video, video-player

I have a video preview widget that takes either a string url or a video file. If the parameter is a String, it downloads the file from online/the cache. With this is mind, my implementation is as follows:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hero/helpers/cache_manager/cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';

class WaveVideoPreview extends StatefulWidget {
  final File? videoFile;
  final String? videoUrl;

  WaveVideoPreview({this.videoFile, this.videoUrl});

  @override
  _WaveVideoPreviewState createState() => _WaveVideoPreviewState();
}

class _WaveVideoPreviewState extends State<WaveVideoPreview> {
  late VideoPlayerController? _controller;
  late ChewieController _chewieController;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initAsync();
  }

  void _initAsync() async {
    File? _videoFile = widget.videoFile;
    if (_videoFile == null) {
      _videoFile = await getVideo(_videoFile);
    }

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(_videoFile!)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _chewieController = ChewieController(
            videoPlayerController: _controller!,
            aspectRatio: _controller!.value.aspectRatio,
            autoPlay: false,
            looping: true,
            allowFullScreen: false,
          );
        });
      });
  }

  Future<File?> getVideo(File? _videoFile) async {
    _videoFile = await MyCache.getVideo(widget.videoUrl!);
    return _videoFile;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: (_controller?.value.isInitialized ?? false)
          ? Chewie(
              controller: _chewieController,
            )
          : SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller!.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

with

```
static Future<File?> getVideo(String url) async {
    DefaultCacheManager _cacheManager = DefaultCacheManager();
    File? file = await _cacheManager.getSingleFile(url);
    return file;
  }
```

Which is throwing the error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following LateError was thrown building WaveVideoPreview(dirty, state: _WaveVideoPreviewState#659ef):
LateInitializationError: Field '_controller@1875314998' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was
WaveVideoPreview
lib/…/widget/wave_tile.dart:84
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _WaveVideoPreviewState._controller (package:hero/screens/home/home_screens/views/waves/widget/video/wave_video_preview.dart)
package:hero/…/video/wave_video_preview.dart:1
#1      _WaveVideoPreviewState.build
package:hero/…/video/wave_video_preview.dart:57
```

Anyone know whats going on? I've tried changing the video player between nullable and non nullable, but still to no avail. Also as you can see i have a null check, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`_initAsync` is using async and it will take some frame to initialize the controllers.

It would be better to use FutureBuilder for this. or make those nullable and the do a null check while using it.

```dart
   VideoPlayerController? _controller;
   ChewieController? _chewieController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the minSdkVersion of your project.
For me, because after adding the package, I only hot reloaded the app, the video display was failing without throwing minSdkVersion error.
Once I stopped the app, ran 'Flutter Clean' and than built the app again, it threw error that required minSdkVersion is at least 24 and yours in 21. Changing it to 24 made it work for me.